# "I played football at 6 o'clock yesterday"

Tags: sentence-construction

which sentence is more correct to express that I started an action in the past:

> 1- I played football at 6 o'clock yesterday
> 2- I started to play football at 6 o'clock yesterday

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is ambiguous.

It might mean that you began playing football at 6.pm or that at 6.pm (when something happened) you were playing football.

The second answer is correct - although many English speakers would probably say **I began playing football at 6.pm yesterday.**

In practice, most people would say that the match started at 6 instead of saying that they started to play at 6.